# comparing each rows with apply() to faster the run

Tags: python, loops, apply

I want to faster my program for comparing each rows with each other. I am thinking about using pandas apply() method but I just cant fiqure it how.

This is the data that I want to compare:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hszbp.png)

I want to compare each rows to become something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpDpm.png)

Currently I am using this code below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'example.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet3')
df['Title_new'] = df[df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
r_list = []
for i in range(len(df['Title_new'])):
    list1 = df['Title_new'][i]
    index_a = df['index'][i]
    source_a = df['Source'][i]
    for j in range(len(df['Title_new'])):
        list2 = df['Title_new'][j]
        index_b = df['index'][j]
        source_b = df['Source'][j]
        if index_a == index_b :
            continue
        r_list.append([index_a,source_a,list1,index_b,source_b,list2])
        print([index_a,source_a,list1,index_b,source_b,list2])

r_df = pd.DataFrame(r_list)
r_df.columns= ['index_a','source_a','title_a','index_b','source_b','title_b']
r_df
```

Comment: At a very minimum, note you're comparing each line with each other twice. `for j in range(i+1,len(df['Title_new'])):` will avoid the issue

Comment: I got an error like 
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: `i` must exist since it is the control variable of the outer loop. What i meant was, replace your `for j...` line with the one I suggested, leaving everything else unchanged

Comment: thanks, but the results between it cost the same amount of time

Comment: The double-loop part should take roughly _half_ the time since for 100 rows you're doing ~5k iterations instead of 10k. The dataframe creation time of course remains the same

Comment: thanks but it makes the results to 1326 rows which the original results is 2652 rows

Comment: Yes, your version creates both a row where row x is compared to row y, and a "mirror" one where y is compared to x, while my suggestion only creates the first one. But if you want both rows then just append them both to your output: after `r_list.append([index_a,source_a,list1,index_b,source_b,list2])` add `r_list.append([index_b,source_b,list2,index_a,source_a,list1])`